# How are action links for posts added in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Certain WordPress plugins add links to the little mini-menu that shows up when hovering over post names in the "All Posts" section. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcBus.png) is what I'm talking about, like Purge from cache or Clone.

How do I add my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old version is not working anymore.

Now use this one:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'search_google', 10, 2);
function search_google($actions, $post) {
    $actions['google_link'] = '<a href="http://google.com/search?q=' . $post->post_title . '" class="google_link">' . __('Search Google for Page Title') . '</a>';
    return $actions;
}
```

And for a custom post type:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'search_google', 10, 2);
function search_google($actions, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type =="YOUR_POST_TYPE"){
        $actions['google_link'] = '<a href="http://google.com/search?q=' . $post->post_title . '" class="google_link">' . __('Search Google for Page Title') . '</a>';
        return $actions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you use the [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) hook

so for example if you want a link to search google for the page title.

add this to your functions.php

```
function search_google($actions, $page_object)
{
   $actions['google_link'] = '<a href="http://google.com/search?q=' . $page_object->post_title . '" class="google_link">' . __('Search Google for Page Title') . '</a>';

   return $actions;
}

add_filter('page_row_actions', 'search_google', 10, 2);
```

for a Custom Post Type

```
add_filter('page_row_actions', 'search_google', 10, 2);
function search_google($actions, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type =="YOUR_POST_TYPE"){
   $actions['google_link'] = '<a href="http://google.com/search?q=' . $page_object->post_title . '" class="google_link">' . __('Search Google for Page Title') . '</a>';

   return $actions;
    }
}
```

more examples can be found [here](http://www.codeforest.net/add-custom-links-to-row-actions-in-wordpress)

Comment: How do I do this for custom post types, like Portfolio?

Comment: Wouldn't add_filter('portfolio_row_actions'...) also work? http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B$taxonomy%7D_row_actions

Comment: I'm not sure this works anymore, I believe "post_row_actions" is the filter you should be using -- I'm working on wp 3.9

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I wanted to both alter the behavior of the current links by having `edit` & `view` open in a new tab and add my own link specific to the Divi Builder theme.  I wanted this to apply to pages, posts and all custom post types.

Because I am applying this change to both pages and posts, I had to do both the  [post_row_actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/) and [page_row_actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_row_actions/) `add_filter` actions.

#### This is the code added to my child theme `functions.php` file.

```
/* Modify row actions */
/* Modify row actions */
/* Modify row actions */

// Open Edit in new
function edit_new_tab( $actions, $page_object ) {
    $actions['edit'] = '<a href="/wp-admin/post.php?post=' . $page_object->ID . '&action=edit" target="_blank">' . __( 'Edit' ) . '</a>';

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'edit_new_tab', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'edit_new_tab', 10, 2 );

// Open View in new
function view_new_tab( $actions, $page_object ) {
    $actions['view'] = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" target="_blank">' . __( 'View' ) . '</a>';

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'view_new_tab', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'view_new_tab', 10, 2 );

// Divi Builder in new
function add_divi_link( $actions, $page_object ) {
    $actions['add_divi_link'] = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '?et_fb=1&PageSpeed=off" target="_blank">' . __( 'Divi Builder' ) . '</a>';

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'add_divi_link', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'add_divi_link', 10, 2 );
```

In this code, `view` in `$actions['view']` matches a built in row type.  Because of this, the row type `view` is overwritten with the respective code.  This also applies to `edit`.  To view the row types and how they appear in your instance you can inspect the source code of the page and pay attention to the `<span>` that surrounds the link you want to modify.  The class of the `<span>` will be the name you will use in `$actions['span_class_goes_here']`.  Therefore, `$actions['edit']` will determine that the Edit link will be modified.

In the case of `$actions['add_divi_link']`, `add_divi_link` does not exist in my scenario so it will be added as a new row action.